# Android Kotlin Official Update App with overwrite Database

Tags: android, sql, kotlin, android-sqlite

I am working hard on an android app with a big SQL Database integrated. With almost every new Update of the App the Database is growing too. On my smartphone I am able to delete the old Database in the System and the new one will be set on update but how should I do that, when other User are using this App with Kotlin language.
I want to replace the whole databse to the new one, but keep one table with saved values.

```
class DatabaseOpenHelper(context: Context) : SQLiteAssetHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION) {
    companion object {
        private const val DATABASE_NAME = "Database.db"
        private const val DATABASE_VERSION = 1
    }
}
```

So how can I change the value
`private const val DATABASE_VERSION = 1`
to a variable in Kotlin in order the device recognise the change of the version. Like my code, he never detects the change.
Edit to the last: I need to change it manually, to gain the `onUpgrade()` on next Start.

And I know I need to work with `onUpgrade()`, when the version differs. How to replace the old Database with the the new one, and copy the important values?

Comment: If you are using Android SQLiteAssetHelper, which is a 3d party library and no longer maintained, visit this page: https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper#android-sqliteassethelper for instructions on how to upgrade the database version.

Comment: Jeah i found some very interested iinformation there for updating, thank you for that hint.